# Length property returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with **length** property returning "undefined" after that I've written my code.

My task is getting length of the text. I've tried out to do it, but it doesn't work.

Let's look at my code and find an error.

```
<h1 id="t">tt</h1>
<input type="submit" value="q" onclick="hide()">
<script>
function hide() {
var qq = document.getElementById('t').length;
alert(qq);
```

}

Friends, I will be grateful, if you will say where is the error. :) 
Thanks in advance.

Having solved the problem, I think you are good.

Comment: What length are you expecting? The content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
var qq = document.getElementById('t').innerHTML.length;
```

instead

as `getElementById` returns a single element `.length` is undefined. `.length` is only available on arrays.

You can access the content of the `<h2>` element by gettings its `innerHTML` property

Comment: I will usually use innerHTML to get length of texts.

Answer (score 5):

`getElementById` returns the element.  You need the text inside the element.  `element.innerHTML` will do the trick in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` does not return text. It returns the DOM element itself.

If you want the content of the HTML emlement, use [`innerHTML`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03) or [`innerText`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04)

```
var qq = document.getElementById('t').innerHTML.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

The document.getElementById('t') just returns the DOM, not a string.
The string is inside on the innerHTML property.

```
var qq = document.getElementById('t');
alert(qq.innerHTML.length);
```